# Why does AJAX break plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins

I have a webpage that loads its content through AJAX calls.

However some plugins will break when I asynchronously load them through AJAX

I try using `jQuery.getScript("/JS-directory-path/add-to-cart-variation.min.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){ });`

to reload the JavaScript files associated with the plugin content that was called through AJAX. This does not do anything to alleviate the issue.

My hunch was that the plugin's content is breaking because the author wrote `$(document).ready(function(){});`'s and these functions were not being re fired on the new AJAX content. Is there a way to bind these new DOM elements to the JS files on the plugin?

The code that is in question that is doing all the Asynchronous loading is as follows:

```
/* AJAX */


$(function(){

    //function for original content
    $('body').delegate('.barnav a, .userpro-awsm-link a, h4 a','click', function(){
        var href = $(this).attr("href");

            //add a history entry to the stack
            history.pushState(null, null, href);

            //AJAX call
            loadContainer(href);

            //break the anchor
            return false;
        });

//loadContent function
var $AJAX = $("#AJAX"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#under-the-table");

function loadContainer(href){
    $AJAX
            .find("#container")
            .fadeOut(250, function() {
                $AJAX.hide().load(href + " #container", function() {
                    $AJAX.fadeIn(250, function() { 
                    });

                            }); 
                });
            });
}


//AJAX for shop to keep category menu intact
$('html').delegate('#content a','click', function(){
        var href = $(this).attr("href");

            //add a history entry to the stack
            history.pushState(null, null, href);

            //AJAX call
            loadContent(href);


            //break the anchor
            return false;
        });

//loadContent function
function loadContent(href){
    $shopJAX = $("#container"),
    $shopWrap = $("#under-the-table"),

    $shopJAX
            .find("#content")
            .fadeOut(250, function() {
               $(this).hide().load(href + " #content", function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn(250, function() { 
                    });

                });

            });
}
if(loadContainer){
//simulates back button
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
   var lol = $(location).attr('href');
   loadContainer(lol);

});     
} else{
//simulates back button
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
   var lol = $(location).attr('href');
   loadContent(lol);

}); 
}
});
```

Comment: You're not really *"reloading"* them, you're loading the same scripts twice, causing naming issues and what not.

Comment: Well regardless, that method is not working, and I want to understand why, and hopefully find a solution. The same thing occurs if I do not load the scripts a second time, and no negative effects of doing this are apparent, behavior does not change at all, also no console errors occur.

Comment: If the plugin doesn't handle dynamically inserted content, there's not much you can do other than rewrite the plugin. Just loading the scripts one more time generally doesn't help at all, you'd have to call the plugin on the new elements only.

Comment: i think this is a textbook example of why jQuery plugins are not good for SPAs; it's the $.ready()...

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.getScript("/JS-directory-path/add-to-cart-variation.min.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){ })
```

This is reloading the script into the DOM. What's happening is that any previously bound handlers or attached events/methods will now be destroyed as the nomenclature has been overwritten. Observe:

```
var a = 1;
console.log(a); //1

var a = 2;
console.log(a); //2
```

This is the same principle with loading custom libraries. You've overwritten a.

What you should be doing is re-invoking the handler for the element instead.

```
$('el').myNiftyFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) the first part makes sense, and now I understand how the events are destroyed by it.

Comment: Do I have to edit the plugin javascript files to utilize `$('el').myNiftyFunction();`? or can I do that from my personal js file?

Comment: You can just reinitialize the plugin on your elements inside of your ajax success function.

Comment: Ok I'll try that I know how to reinitialize functions, but how would you reinitialize a whole plugin? I tried a google search but came up with nothing. Is there any documentation on targeting a whole plugin?

Comment: Can you drop in some code in your question so I can further advise

Comment: Ok, I just inserted the code that does all my asynchronous loading :D

I use `.load()` for everything, and it does everything I need it too, however, the plugins break. would replacing `.load()` with `$.ajax()` be better?